# PHP not be able to echo data

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP not be able to echo data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048618/php-not-be-able-to-echo-data)

I'm trying to get data from database, and echo them on the page using their unique id.. below is my code

```
<?php

 session_start();

require_once('config.php');

    //create query statement
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM player_info';

    //make the query from db
    $myData = mysql_query($query, $conn)
    OR exit('Unable to select data from table');




    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 


                $playerID       = $row['id']; 
                $player_bio     = $row['player_bio']; 
                $achievements   = $row['player_achts'];


    }
```

?>

and here is how i code for echo the data

```
<?php

                             if ($playerID == 1)
                             {
                                echo '<p class="playerAchievesL">' . $achievements . '</p><p class="playerInfoL">' . $player_bio . '</p>';
                             }

                             ?>
```

I don't get any error return from php, but the data does not display anything... help please ... thank you so much

Comment: Repost of [PHP not be able to echo data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048618/php-not-be-able-to-echo-data)

Comment: Please don't repost questions. If the answers in the previous question didn't work for you, edit the old question with more details.

Comment: Please stop posting duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to place the echo inside the `while()` loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 

            $playerID       = $row['id']; 
            $player_bio     = $row['player_bio']; 
            $achievements   = $row['player_achts'];

            echo '<p class="playerAchievesL">' . $achievements . '</p><p class="playerInfoL">' . $player_bio . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You fetch all players from the table, and for each player, overwrite `$playerID`, `$player_bio` and `$achievements`. After the `while` loop, `$playerID` contains the identifier of the last fetched player.

If you have more than one player, this most likely is not `$playerID` with `1`.

Answer (score 1):

problem is in here. you're overwriting the values on every iteration

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 


            $playerID       = $row['id']; 
            $player_bio     = $row['player_bio']; 
            $achievements   = $row['player_achts'];


}
```

Just echo them directly in the loop:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 


            echo $row['id']; 
            echo $row['player_bio']; 
            echo $row['player_achts'];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop may be overwriting $pkayerID, so if the last playerID isn't 1 the it won't echo anything.

Try putting the echo line after the $achievemets line to see if this is the case.